# pip: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

Tags: python, pip, openai-gym

I tried running `pip install gym==0.21.0`

but got the cryptic error:

```
Collecting gym==0.21.0
  Using cached gym-0.21.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in gym setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

What may be causing this error?

Comment: As it says: *This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.* - Maybe try to contact the owner of the package?

Comment: Well, this is a very important package used by thousands of people everyday, so it is not some basic error in the package for the developer to fix, but instead some problem with my environment somehow.

Comment: Well despite the many users, not all packages are free of bugs. Would be better to ask directly on the Github.

Comment: `pip --version` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the comments in the issue section at https://github.com/openai, these are the changes that need to be made -

1. `pip install setuptools==65.5.0 pip==21  # gym 0.21 installation is broken with more recent versions`
2. `pip install wheel==0.38.0`

I was facing the same issue and after doing the above, it was resolved.

The problem has been addressed [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3176) and [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/3211).

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem for me.  FYI, after making the changes, I got a warning from GitHub's 'dependabot' recommending "bump setuptools from 65.5.0 to 65.5.1" for security reasons.  I did this and the gym==0.21.0 installation still works.