# How do you define a Python package's requirements when an older version of pip and setuptools are needed to install?

Tags: python, pip, package, openai-gym

I have an old [Open AI gym environment](https://github.com/billtubbs/gym-CartPole-bt-v0/tree/master/gym_CartPole_BT/envs) in a GitHub repo which requires gym==0.21.0 and pyglet==1.5.27. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77205046/1609514) I found I can still install and run these versions provided I use an older version of pip and setuptools (pip==21 and setuptools=65.5.0).

How should I update my package and ReadMe file to explain how to install it for other users?

Should I put everything in the requirements.txt file as follows:

```
pip==21.0
setuptools==65.5.0
wheel==0.38.0
cloudpickle==3.0.0
numpy==1.26.3
scipy==1.12.0
gym==0.21.0
pyglet==1.5.27
```

I tried this but running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

doesn't work, presumably because the current/default pip version tries to install everything.

Is it therefore necessary to tell the user to do it in two steps:

1. first install the correct pip and setuptools versions (e.g. in a new environment),
2. and then proceed with the installation in the usual way, i.e.

```
pip install -e .
```

(This works, I'm just not sure it is the best way to do it).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a bash(Unix)/cmd(Windows) script, which would install right version of pip in the first place and then proceed with installing all the dependencies.

Something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash
pip install pip==21.0
pip install setuptools==65.5.0
pip install -e .
```

And add info in ReadMe.md about installing dependencies using the script file rather than manually invoking pip commands, so newcomers would know about it too.

Then all you/they would need to do is run the script file.